# Entity Framework Code First derived model not getting set as a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

I have a class ApplicationUser derived from IdentityUser. I use ApplicationUser class in Asp.Net Identity to create membership tables. I have kept all the functionalities related to membership compiled into a DLL.

Now in my another project I am using this DLL. In this project I am using Code First to generate the database.
I have a model like this

```
class Company
{
int CompanyID{get;set;}
string UserID {get;set;} //Foreign Key to the ApplicationUser "Id" column
virtual ApplicationUser {get;set;}
}
```

Now in my code first DBContext I want to use the ApplicationUser as a navigation property from the Company model.

How can I achieve this without touching the ApplicationUser class in the separate DLL?

Comment: [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser ")]  string UserID {get;set;}     is this wat you want?

Comment: UserID is the foreign key but what I want is the ApplicationUser entity as a navigation property in the Company model.

So that when i get the company object i should be able to navigate to the ApplicationUser entity.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve this.

First, using `DataAnnotations`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
class Company
{
    public int CompanyID{get;set;}
    public string UserID {get;set;} 
    [ForeignKey("UserID ")]//Tells to EF that UserId is corresponds to this navigation prop
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser{get;set;}
}
```

Second, using model builder in the `Context` class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(x => x.ApplicationUser)
                    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);
    }
```